# how to plot candlestick + roller in dygraphs [r]

Tags: dygraphs, r-dygraphs

Hi I try to plot a candlestick plot + roller average line.

```
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)
data(sample_matrix)
m <- tail(sample_matrix, n = 32)

dygraph(m) %>% 
    dyCandlestick() %>% 
    dyRoller(showRoller = T, rollPeriod = 5)
```

yields this:

[image]

What I want is candlestick plot + roller average line, like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dyRoller is a rolling average period **text box** added to the chart. What you want are moving averages of the closing price. Here is sample code. Function TTR::SMA (quantmod) could be replaced with forecast::ma.

```
library(dygraphs); library(xts); library(quantmod)
data(sample_matrix)
m <- tail(sample_matrix, n=75)
m <- cbind(m, SMA(m[,4], n=10))
m <- cbind(m, SMA(m[,4], n=20))
colnames(m)[5:6] <- c('SMA10','SMA20')
dygraph(m) %>% 
  dyCandlestick()
```

[image]